# Exporting lat/lon of ST_EndPoint

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

In the query below I am exporting only the endpoint of linestrings in my table `routes` to a json file.

My objective, however, is to export to a csv, with four separate columns - `starttime`, `endtime`, `lat` and `lon`

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON endpoints.json  "PG:host=localhost dbname=dbname user=user password=password"  -sql "SELECT ST_AsText(ST_EndPoint(path::geometry)) from routes"
```

How could I change the query in psql below to include latitude and longitude of the endpoints as separate columns, using `ST_AsText(ST_EndPoint(path::geometry))` ?

```
   \COPY (
        SELECT starttime, endtime, lat, lon from routes
    ) TO 'endpoints.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

Comment: What's the structure of your `routes` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ST_X and ST_Y [Geometry Accessors](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors) to get the point coordinate values:

```
SELECT starttime, endtime, ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geom)) AS lat, ST_X(ST_EndPoint(geom)) AS lon
FROM routes;
```

There is also [ST_AsLatLonText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html) for a human-readable format.